How to ignore service dependencies that belong to a different profile in Docker Compose?
In a local environment I can use this command to start both the db and core services:
docker compose --profile local up core

But is it possible to start the core service and solely ignore its dependency on the db service in production? If so, how to do it?
version: "3.3"
services:
  core:
    ...
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      other:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    ...
    profiles: ["local"]


